# Developing a simple cloud data processing system

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, google-cloud-platform, cloud, data-processing

What would be the most simple way to take a public data API, for example, and schedule a daily job to calculate a set of statistics and land the computed statistics in a cloud database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using [CloudWatch Event rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) with [Schedule Expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html) and a target of a `Lambda` function?

The event **rule would trigger** your `Lambda` function, e.g., once a day. The function would then call the API,  process the data from the API, and write the results into a `DynamoDB` or `RDS` database, depending whether you require relational or non-SQL database.

Answer (score 2):

Same on GCP. You can use Cloud Scheduler for the periodic trigger, and call a Cloud Functions that perform your statistics.

You can use Firestore for storing your data in document format.

The free tiers of each product are huge and if your processing is simple and not running full time, you should pay nothing.